# Confusion about the convergence of Riemann zeta function in terms of the integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, special-functions, proof-explanation

Titchmarsh wrote that
$$\zeta(s)=s\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-x+\frac{1}{2}}{x^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2}\tag{2.14}$$
using the Euler-Maclaurin summation, for all $\Re s > 1$. Since the integral converges absolutely for all $\Re s > 0$, this equation now holds for $\Re s > 0$ and $s\neq 1$.

But below says that this integral converges for all $\Re s > -1$. I do not understand why. If you rewrite this integral using the integration by parts the new integral converges absolutely for all $\Re s > -1$, but how does this imply that it goes same for the original integral? Or is there something I am missing?

Let $s=\sigma+it$. Let $f(x)=\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-x+\frac{1}{2}$ and $f_1(x):=\int_{1}^{x}f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$.

> Actually (2.1.4) gives the analytic continuation for $\zeta(s)$ for $\sigma>-1;$
>
> [...]
>
> Hence $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{f(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\left [ \frac{f_1(x)}{x^{s+1}} \right ]_{x_1}^{x_2}+(s+1)\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{f_1(x)}{x^{s+2}}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
>   which tends to $0$ as $x_1\to\infty$, $x_2\to\infty$, if $\sigma>-1$. Hence the integral in (2.1.4) is convergent for $\sigma>-1$.
>
> [Source, p. 14-15](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-theory-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-9780198533696?cc=dk&lang=en&)